# DDD, MMMM, YYYY, HH: MM nested script in word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, time, date-time, date

I need to "nest" a script to include DDDD, MMMM, YYYY, \ HH:MM to portray like this;  Saturday, March 15, 2018, 09:40 AM.

I know how to write the date and the time separately but I would like to know how to nest the time script along with the date script into only 1 script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is VBA script that would give you something like it.

```
Sub FileDate_Time()
    Dim LDate As Date, LString As String
    LDate = Now
    LString = WeekdayName(Weekday(LDate)) & "," & Format(LDate, "yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss")
    Selection.TypeText LString
End Sub
```

Comment: I went into my document, placed the cursor over the spot where I wanted the date and time and ran this macro that you provided me with; nothing happened.  I did not get an error message either. The macro was recorded  as having been executed on the Immediate dialog box.  ????

Comment: I thought you'd understand how to alter it. Anyway I made the adjustment to the last line and will now add the date/time string at the selection point in your document.